# How we can show UIViewController and UIView by using Cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to build an iPhone app by using Cocos2d.But i have used four types of classes
like bellow-

```
@interface MenuScene : Scene {}

@end
@interface FlipView : UIImageView
{
    CGPoint startTouchPosition;
    NSString *dirString;
    UIImageView *firstPieceView;   
    UIImageView *secondPieceView;

}
@end

@interface HelloController : UIViewController
@end


@interface MenuLayer: Layer{
        Todo *todo;
        Menu * menu;
        sqlite3 *database;
        NSMutableArray *todos;
    NSString *dirString;
    CGPoint startTouchPosition;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *todos;
-(void) button1: (id)sender;
-(void) button2: (id)sender;
-(void) black_jack: (id)sender;
@end
```

but how can i show FlipView and HelloController class through MenuLayer class.

Answer (score 20):

If you are asking how to attach UIKit views and such to a cocos2d-iphone project, you just have to do it like:

```
[[[Director sharedDirector] window] addSubview:myView];
```

Updated to cocos 0.7 and now this is:

```
[[[Director sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:myView];
```

And in Cocos 0.99:

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:myView];
```

And in Cocos 2.0

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:myView];
```

Comment: What shouldI do to remove myView. When I press a button in present scene I move to next scene. But, the added myView is still appearing in that scene too.
Thank You.

Comment: Sorry I did not check well before asking. I got it. I added the following code in the selector for the button. 

for (id sv in subviews)
 {
         [((UIView *)sv) removeFromSuperview];
         [sv release];
 }

Comment: one more question. is it possible to awake UIView from nib?

Comment: At the moment for version 2 `[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:myView];`

Answer (score 2):

It's very difficult to answer this question just from the code but I think you need to go back and read up a little on UIKit design and cocos2d programming.

HelloController is a view controller - you cannot 'show' it. A view controller is a class that replies to messages from a view and controls the data it displays from the model.

FlipView is an ImageView which is a subclas of UIView. To have UIKit render this image, you need to add it to another view using `[UIView addSubView:...]`

Here's what I think you want to do:

1. The menu item receives a touch event. It signals to:
2. the view controller which
3. adds the UIImage to the main view

Like I said though, this is a very general question and I really think you should go back to the documentation and think about your design. The Apple docs are good and there are some good iPhone books on the market now.