# Cocos2d for this?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I just finished my concept for an iphone app. I have a main program and in that program I want to start a game.

MAIN PROGRAM (BUTTON 1 / BUTTON 2 / START GAME)
                                        |
                                        |
                                    Cocos2d Game

Is this possible? To use cocos2D in a normal "iphone app"???

Thanks so much!!!

Comment: A game, written using Cocos2d or with any other technology is a normal iphone app. It sound like you are describing the opening screen on "Monkey Flight" which has three buttons: start, options, more games. But, perhaps you need to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: Cocos2D is not limited to games.  How would it be?  You can do anything you have the skill to do with it.

Answer (score 7):

It is definitely possible to mix UIKit with Cocos2d. Usually people accomplish this by putting their [UIKit views inside a Cocos2d layer](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/tips:cocos2d_and_uikitlayer). It sounds like you want to embed the Cocos2d game inside a UIKit view instead. This should be possible, but I am unsure of the specifics involved. Try looking at `-(BOOL)attachInView:(UIView *) view` in CCDirector.

Note that Cocos2d uses OpenGL and there are possible performance issues when mixing OpenGL and UIKit. Pausing Cocos2d when using the other part of your application will help.

Answer (score 5):

I found a vast array of great tutorials on Cocos2D for iPhone at [Ray Wenderlich's site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials). One tutorial you might especially want to check out is
[How to integrate Cocos2D and UIKit](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4817/how-to-integrate-cocos2d-and-uikit)

Note: the original "Cocos2D" framework was written in Python and not designed for iOS; here's the [actual homepage](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) for the iOS port.

Comment: I agree that Ray Wenderlich's site is a great starting point for beginners to Cocos2d. He really dives right in and you will get your hands dirty with working game code very quickly. Awesome resource.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible, but you should know that the main core of your app must be controlled by Cocos2D, that means CCDirector needs to be instantiated in AppDelegate.

Start with:

a). install Cocos2D:

Go to Terminal and write (if you save cocos2D file in desktop, if not use the path where you save it)

```
    cd  Desktop/cocos2d-iphone-1.1-beta
    sudo ./install-templates.sh
```

and if you couldn't install try again with

```
    ./install-templates.sh -f -u
```

b). Import cocos2d.h inside AppDelegate

c). Declare CCDirector in applicationDidFinishLaunching method inside
    AppDelegate (you should check the code for this in Cocos2D template is pretty straight
    forward)

I did this in my applicationDidFinishLaunching method:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

[window setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[window setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];

CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

// Create an EAGLView with a RGB8 color buffer, and a depth buffer of 24-bits
EAGLView *glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:[window frame]
                               pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565   // kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                               depthFormat:0                        // GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES
                    ];

[glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES]; 

// attach the openglView to the director
[director setOpenGLView:glView];

// Enables High Res mode (Retina Display) on iPhone 4 and maintains low res on all other devices
if( ! [director enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
    CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");

// make the OpenGLView a child of the main window
[window addSubview:glView];

// make main window visible
[window makeKeyAndVisible]; 

GameScene *gs = [GameScene node];

[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:gs];
//General is part of UIKit where I load the tabbar
General *principal;
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    principal = [[General alloc] initWithNibName:@"General-iPad" bundle:nil];
} else {
    principal = [[General alloc] initWithNibName:@"General" bundle:nil];
}
self.general = principal;
[principal release];
[self showUIViewController:general];
```

}

To push a scene from tabbar in UIKit

```
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene: [CCTransitionMoveInB transitionWithDuration:0.0f scene:[MyScene scene]]];
```

Next I recommend you to follow Ray Wenderlich's tutorial [How to integrate Cocos2D and UIKit](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4817/how-to-integrate-cocos2d-and-uikit) and read this post aswell [how we can show UIViewController and UIView by using cocos2d?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506680/how-we-can-show-uiviewcontroller-and-uiview-by-using-cocos2d) Maybe you should search for some code in the Cocos2D forums too, always help to see that.

EDIT:

1) You can download a easy example from here: [UIKit Cocos2D](http://phyline.com/blog/codigoCocos2D/uikitcocos/Pruebauikit.zip)

You could check out this framework too: Kobol2D "is an extended and improved version of the popular Cocos2D for iPhone game engine. Everything you know about Cocos2D can still be applied, and Kobold2D is easier to get started with, more convenient to use, more powerful and flexible than Cocos2D with all the documentation available online and offline. Use Kobold2D to develop iPhone, iPod touch, iPad and Mac OS X games for both Apple App Stores. And it has some examples using UIKIT and Cocos2D".

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly create a game with your requirements in Cocos2D.  You might want to ask some follow-up questions over at the [Cocos2D forums](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/) and read through [their documentation](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php).

Answer (score 2):

You can probably do this easily......

You have to only make the (UIView *) view in CCDirector.

after attaching the view.....

Answer (score 0):

Yes.It is very easy and handy to implement Cocos2D with normal Iphone FrameWork.Refer Ray Wenderlich UIKit and Cocos2D Integration Tutorial [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601116/cocos2d-for-this).It will helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Is very possible, only install the Cocos2d and his templates.
Inclusive, I used Cocos2d to create simple apps with a lot of effects :)