# How to integrate UIImagepickerview in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Can anybody please help me out with my question any help will be appericiated.
Question-

How do i integrate UIImagePickerView in cocos2d ?

I have gone through many links and had also googled too much but cant find myself any better help so please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure but i think you can do it the same way you normally create a UIImagePickerView and then add it to the screen using:

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:ImagePickerView];
```

Here is the link to another question on SO:

[How we can show UIViewController and UIView by using Cocos2d?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506680/how-we-can-show-uiviewcontroller-and-uiview-by-using-cocos2d)

Comment: I have already tried that thing but didn't work after doing this the only thing i got is a strip which remains on the screen until you close the application.

Comment: To be honest i have never used a UIImagePickerView. But i believe that is what happens when you have not initialized in right… are you sure your Delegate and Datasource was set up right?

Comment: @interface AboutScene : CCLayer <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
 
 UIWindow *window;
 UIImage *newImage;

}

here you go budy I have done everything and have also added delegate methods for UIImagePickerView but still having badluck!!!!